# Суперглобальный массив $GLOBAL

Tags: php, global-variables

У меня есть два файла 1.php и 2.php. Во втором файле (2.php) в суперглобальный массив $GLOBAL['array'] записывается значение к примеру "12345".

Мне нужно в файле 1.php получить это значение из массива $GLOBAL['array'], без подключения (include) файла 2.php.

```
//файл 1.php
<?php print_r($GLOBAL['array']); >?

//файл 2.php
$GLOBAL['array'] = '12345';
```

Возможно этот массив можно передать POST или GET методом, или как-то ещё?

Comment: Не понятно как эти 2 файла связаны? Через пользователский интерфейс(ссылка) в браузере? Передать значение во второй файл, без предварительного запуска(или включения[require|include]) первого,  ни как не получиться. Способов много но будет зависить от ситуации.

Comment: @E_p
Дело в том, что я разбираю древний, самописный движок, в файле 2.php в массив $GLOBALS вписываются нужные мне значения, но если подключить 2.php к моему 1.php, для того чтобы просто вытащить эти данные, то он начинает всё сыпать, т.к. 2.php по сути является страницой, которая перекрывает мою (1.php).

Comment: @E_p
Поэтому я и думаю, как бы вытащить этот массив $GLOBALS без подключения самого файла.

Comment: Скопировать создание массива в третий файл и подключить его?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Постом в `JSON` и декодировать там где тебе нужно.

При получении:
`$array=json_decode($_POST["array"], true);`

При отправке:
`<тутURL>/?array=<тутJSONстрока>`

Comment: Очень куцый ответ. Если есть возможность - приведите пример.